# 200 HTTP CODE at non-url strings

Tags: http, curl, http-status-codes, http-status-code-200

```
$agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";
$ch=curl_init();
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
   curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
   $page=curl_exec($ch);
   //echo curl_error($ch);
   $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
   curl_close($ch);
```

I'm using cUrl at my project.  I'm getting HTTP CODE of web sites. But when i try "asdasd" ($url="asdasd") , returned HTTP CODE is 200 . But "asdasd" isn't a web site. Why HTTP CODE is 200 ?

Comment: What about `curl_error`? Does it return anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the return value from `curl_exec` first. It says in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

> Returns **`TRUE`** on success or **`FALSE`** on failure. However, if the **`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`** option is set, it will return the result on success, **`FALSE`** on failure.

For `curl_getinfo` there's a [side note](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php):

> Information gathered by this function is kept if the handle is re-used. This means that unless a statistic is overridden internally by this function, the previous info is returned.

So that HTTP 200 might well be the result of a previous cURL invocation.

Comment: so, i should set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to FALSE . Right? Or i misunderstood ?

Comment: @Eray Um... No. Not necessarily. My answer is about finding out, whether or not the actual request was successful. In either case (**`CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`** set, or not), `curl_exec()` will return `FALSE` in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible error can happen if you develop in local and you use custom managed DNS services, then you probably can get some managed error pages like OpenDNS is doing.